# Full width table with caption in refman doc

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions, margins

The `refman` document class has a big left margin for text. Only the headings are on the normal left margin.  Perfect for what I'm doing.

But I have a wide table (float) that must be centered on the full page width (like `table*` in two-column mode).

So far closest to success is the `changepage` package `adjustwidth` environment. It takes care of the table (`tabular` env) just fine.

But the caption remains centered with respect to the wide left margin, even though it's inside the `adjustwidth`.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{refart}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage} 
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Here is some normal text at the normal margin.
Now let's insert wide Table~\ref{tbl:thetable}. \begin{table}
% Uncommenting this environment will move the 
    % table contents left, but not the caption!
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5in}{}
\caption{The caption.}
\begin{tabular}{>{\sf}llp{7cm}}
{\bf Schedule item} & {\bf Type} & {\bf Description} \\ \hline 
Start semifinals logins & 
      date & 
      semifinalists can log in to either 
      home page but not submit semifinal designs\\
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:thetable}
%\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
And finish with more text.
\end{document}
```

This is frustrating!  How can both table and caption be convinced to use full width?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg Done with MWE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to back up by `\leftmarginwidth`; enclosing the table in a `minipage` will accomplish the centering.

The `lipsum` package is just to provide filler text.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{refart}
\usepackage{array,lipsum}

\newenvironment{fulltable}[1][tbp]
 {\begin{table}[#1]%
  \hspace*{-\leftmarginwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{\fullwidth}}
 {\end{minipage}\end{table}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Here is some normal text at the normal margin.
Now let's insert wide Table~\ref{tbl:thetable}.

\begin{fulltable}
\centering
\caption{The caption.}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{>{\sffamily}llp{7cm}}
\bfseries Schedule item & \bfseries Type & \bfseries Description \\
\hline 
Start semifinals logins & 
      date & 
      semifinalists can log in to either 
      home page but not submit semifinal designs\\
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:thetable}
\end{fulltable}

And finish with more text.
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks. Looks great. Have not done LaTeX for some years and I appreciate the memory jog.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer. But for people who may be having problems with full pages and refman, refart, refrep, etc.

Just enclose what you want within a fullpage environment.

```
\begin{fullpage}

\end{fullpage}
```

You don't need to define anything. It is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.